# Cannot save or compile document on new computer

Tags: mac, texshop

I recently got myself a new laptop, MacBook with Ventura 13.1, and I installed LaTeX on it. I have no problem saving and compiling .tex documents that I have transferred over from another computer, however, when I try to create a new document, the editor (TexShop), refuses to save the documents, and it refuses to compile them. I get no error messages or anything, nothing happens. Worse, when I try to close the editor, nothing happens still. When I force quit TexShop and reopen it, the unsaved documents suddenly appear.

It seems to me that this probably has *something* to do with the fact that I have never specified a default location for TexShop to save new documents to, but I am unable to figure out how to solve it.

Any and all help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: How do you try to save the file? With `save` or `save as` or something else?

Comment: With *save,* as *save as* for some reason is not even an option. That and just good old fashioned command+S.

Comment: Try to hold the alt or option key while opening the file menu. This should show `save as`

Comment: (might be related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337805/texshop-unable-to-save-files)

Comment: Ah, save as appears now, but unfortunately, clicking on it doesn't do anything either. I shall have a look at the link you provided.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but unfortunately, it seems unrelated to my problems, in as far as I can make it out. That said, I shall look further into autosave.

Comment: As `save as` does not work, by guess would be that texshop lacks some permissions. In MacOS 11, settings to grant access are in  system perferences -> Security & Privacy, no idea where they are in Ventura

Comment: Once in a while I forget to save as <filename>.tex, i.e. miss the extension, irritating Texmaker. Can it be as simple as that? // Not sure, if and how permissions are set and administrated on a MacBook.

Comment: This post claims that full disk access is necessary https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/579363/36296

Comment: I've given it full disk access now, that doesn't help. I'm a bit confused about the comment about needing to save as <filename>.tex, since when I try to save the document, no window comes up into which I may type in a name or anything for the document in question.

Answer (score 2):

No idea what the problem was, but I was able to solve it by uninstalling and re-installing TexShop. Hope the problem doesn't occur once more.